# User Inbox Functionality

Tags: asp.net, email

How do achieve this functionality in Asp.net. Users should be able to compose messages. 
Once the user logs in, he should see a list of profile ids on the homepage. these profile ids should be hyperlinks. this homepage also contains a header link 'Message Center'. once the user clicks on any profile in this profile list, show the 'Compose Message' form as shown in pdf file.

Thanks
SC

Comment: So you essentially want to write a web-based email client? And you want people on SO to do it for you?

Comment: I love these questions. Should we code it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.Net and SQL Server. Read documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/).

Comment: exactly! This is the way to go.